# Network Printers, Group Policy & Normal Users

Tags: group-policy, network-printer, multiple-users

I have a strange issue and I am wondering if someone can explain the answer to me. My system is running a GPO with a security policy. Within that policy I have the following setting enabled:

```
Devices: Prevent users from installing printer drivers
```

With this sent to enabled users are unable to install printers on their own.

The question is if I deploy 3 printers through Print Management to my group policy and set it to install the printers **PER MACHINE** and not **PER USER** it still does not install the printer for the user. Why is that if the setting that is allowing the printer to be installed per user is not checked? The group policy shows the deployed printer as being pushed per machine so when the computer turns on and is recognized by the network it should add the printer before the user logs in, correct?

Can anyone shine some light on this issue?